# pandas .drop under condition issue

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove all the rows that contains 'NaN' under column Relinquished, but .drop doesn't seem to work

```
indexNames = df[df['Relinquished'] == 'NaN'].index
df.drop(indexNames, inplace=True)
df.head(40)
```

Comment: Likely the values are actually `NaN`, not the string `'NaN'`. No need to slice and then drop, you can just select the non-null subset with:`df[df['Relinquished'].notnull()]`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html). You can specify which columns to look for `NaN` with `subset`:

```
df.dropna(subset=['Relinquished'], inplace=True)
```